# How search engines find websites over internet

Tags: web, dns, find, search-engine

I'm going to write a Web parser (an application that crawles on the web from one site to another).
How Can I find list of available domains/IPs in the internet (as complete as possible)?
How search engines find websites (What they use as a reliable list of registred IP/Domains for starting point)?

Thanks

Comment: What is your definition of a "web parser"?

Comment: I mean an application that finds each web site on the web and creates and ID for it and saves that ID

Answer (score 1):

As Michael P's comment indicates, depends on what your objective is.

My company recently wanted to answer a question about third-party tools used on leading websites. I used [Alexa](http://www.alexa.com/) as a starting point to find the top (by traffic) websites, and created a parser that can answer the specific question my company asked.  If you start from such a list, you can program your web crawler to follow the links it encounters to broaden your knowledge of sites on the web.

Hopefully that helps you think about the problem.